# Invoking a dataproc workflow from yaml file using cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataproc, google-workflows

I am trying to write a Google cloud function that invokes a Dataproc workflow from a YAML template stored in a storage bucket. The template must accept parameters. I have pieced together what I have so far from various sources, and I feel like I am running in circles trying to get this right.

The relevant bits from the function are here:

```py
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1 as dataproc, storage
from google.cloud.dataproc_v1.types.workflow_templates import WorkflowTemplate, ParameterValidation

def submit_workflow(parameters, date_fmt):
    '''Initialises a DataProc workflow from a yaml file'''
    # workflow vars
    workflow_file = '{0}-app/xxx-workflow.yaml'.format(project_id)

    try:
        # create client
        client = dataproc.WorkflowTemplateServiceClient()

        # build workflow parameter map
        parameter_map = []
        for k, v in parameters.items():
            parameter_map.append(ParameterValidation(
                name=k,
                value=ParameterValidation.Value(values=[v])
            ))

        # create template
        template_name = f'projects/{0}/regions/{1}/workflowTemplates/{2}'.format(project_id, region, workflow_file)
        workflow_template = WorkflowTemplate(
            parameters=parameter_map,
            template=WorkflowTemplate.Template(id=template_name)
        )

        # create request
        workflow_request = dataproc.InstantiateWorkflowTwmplateRequest(
            parent=parameters['regionUri'],
            template=workflow_template
        )

        # run workflow
        operation = client.instantiate_workflow_template(request=workflow_request)
    except Exception as e:
        message = ':x: An error has occurred invoking the workflow. Please check cloud function log.\n{}'.format(e)
        post_to_slack(url, message)
    else:
        # wait for workflow to complete
        result = operation.result()
        print(result)

        # post completion to slack
        message = 'run is complete for {}'.format(date_fmt)
        post_to_slack(url, message)
```

The current error I am getting is `type object 'ParameterValidation' has no attribute 'Value'` and I feel like I am going around in circles trying to find the best way to implement this. Any advice would be fantastic.

Comment: Can you try to write your workflow_file template like that `'{0}-app%2Fxxx-workflow.yaml'`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere sorry I don't understand what you're asking me

Comment: Sorry. I will try differently. Replace this line `workflow_file = '{0}-app/xxx-workflow.yaml'.format(project_id)` by this one, and test again `workflow_file = '{0}-app%2Fxxx-workflow.yaml'.format(project_id)`

Comment: That had no effect sorry.

Comment: Arf, understood. The parameterValidation has an attribute named `values` with a S. You forgot it! `value=ParameterValidation.Value(values=[v])` More detail here https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/dataproc/latest/google.cloud.dataproc_v1.types.ParameterValidation

Comment: And there is also no Value() function on this class. Your code is strange there!